# Convert Oracle Select to Linq to implement the entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I tried to create an Web API which is accessing the Oracle DB by directly accessing the database. But now trying to replace them with the entity framework.The Query that is being used is very complex and it something like below

```
SELECT                     STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR.DESCR AS CATEGORY, 
                           STRS_SESSION3.SESSION_NUM AS SESSION_NUMBER, 
                           Trunc(STRS_SESSION3.START_DATE) AS SESSION_START_DATE, 
                           STRS_SESSION3.START_DATE AS SESSION_START_TIME , 
                           Trunc(STRS_SESSION3.END_DATE) AS SESSION_END_DATE, 
                           STRS_SESSION3.END_DATE AS SESSION_END_TIME,
                           Round((TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (STRS_SESSION3.END_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') - TO_DATE (TO_CHAR (STRS_SESSION3.START_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'),'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi'))*1440)AS SESSION_DURATION_MINUTES,
                           STCD_ACT_DESCR4.DESCR AS DOSE_ACTIVITY, 
                           decode(( decode(sign(( DECODE(SIGN(( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) )),-1,'Y',0,'N','N') ), 'N', Decode (( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN ), '1', trunc((( DECODE(SIGN(( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) )-1) /7)+1, '0', trunc(( DECODE(SIGN(( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) )/7)), 'Y', (trunc((( DECODE(SIGN(( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) ) +1)/ 7)-1) , -999) AS RESULT_WEEK,
                           DECODE(SIGN(( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) AS RESULT_DAY,
                           Trunc(ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE) AS RESULT_DATE, 
                           ILRS_DOSE.RESULT_DATE AS RESULT_TIME, 
                           STPR_STD_ANML.ANML_REF AS ANIMAL_NAME, 
                           STPR_GRP.LONG_NAME AS GROUP_NAME, 
                           decode(STPR_ANML.SEX,0,'Male',1,'Female',2,'Herm','--') AS SEX, 
                           STPR_STUDY.STD_REF AS STUDY_NUMBER, 
                           STCD_TA_DESCR.COMMON_NAME_1 AS COMPOUND, 
                           STPR_DOSE_DET.TA_AMOUNT AS TEST_MATERIAL_AMOUNT, 
                           trim(STCD_ADMIN_ROUTE_DESCR.DESCR)AS ROUTE_OF_ADMINISTRATION, 
                           STCD_UNIT_DESCR.DESCR AS ADMINISTRATION_ROUTE_UNITS, 
                           STCD_VEH_SOLV_DESCR.DESCR AS VEHICLE, 
                           decode(sign(( DECODE(SIGN(( trunc(ILRS_ANML.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )),-1,( trunc(ILRS_ANML.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) ),( trunc(ILRS_ANML.RESULT_DATE) ) - ( trunc(STPR_STD_ANML.START_DATE) )+( STPR_OPTIONS.VALUEN )) )),-1,'Y',0,'N','N') AS PRE_STUDY_DATA
                             FROM 
                             STPR_STD_ANML, 
                             STPR_ANML, 
                             STPR_OPTIONS, 
                             STCD_ACT_DESCR STCD_ACT_DESCR4, 
                             STCD_ACT_DESCR, 
                             STCD_UNIT_DESCR, 
                             STCD_UNIT_DESCR STCD_UNIT_DESCR2, 
                             STCD_UNIT_DESCR STCD_UNIT_DESCR10, 
                             STCD_ACT STCD_ACT4, 
                             STCD_ACT, 
                             STCD_RESRCE_DESCR STCD_RESRCE_DESCR1, 
                             STCD_RESRCE_DESCR, 
                             STCD_UNIT, 
                             STCD_UNIT STCD_UNIT2, 
                             STCD_UNIT STCD_UNIT10, 
                             STCD_STUDY_TYPE_DESCR, 
                             STPR_GRP, 
                             STCD_RESRCE STCD_RESRCE2, 
                             STCD_RESRCE STCD_RESRCE1, 
                             STCD_RESRCE, 
                             STPR_DOSE_DET, 
                             STCD_STRAIN_DESCR, 
                             STCD_STUDY_TYPE, 
                             STCD_ADMIN_ROUTE_DESCR, 
                             STCD_VEH_SOLV_DESCR, 
                             STPR_STUDY, 
                             STCD_SPECIES_DESCR, 
                             STPR_STUDY_DET, 
                             STPR_KEY_PERS, 
                             STPR_STD_SPECIES, 
                             STCD_STRAIN, 
                             STCD_ADMIN_ROUTE, 
                             STPR_ROOM, 
                             STCD_VEH_SOLV, 
                             STPR_TREATMT, 
                             STCD_SPECIES, 
                             STCD_USER, 
                             STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY_DESCR, 
                             STRS_SESSION STRS_SESSION3, 
                             ILRS_DOSE, 
                             STCD_TA_DESCR, 
                             ILRS_ANML, 
                             STCD_STUDY_STATUS_DESCR, 
                             STCD_PRIO_CATEGORY, 
                             STCD_TA, 
                             STPR_CMPND, 
                             STCD_STUDY_STATUS, 
                             STPR_BUS_AREA 
                             WHERE 
                             ( STPR_STUDY.ID=STPR_STUDY_DET.STD_ID ) 
                             AND ( STPR_STUDY_DET.STD_TYPE_ID=STCD_STUDY_TYPE.ID ) 
                             AND ( STCD_STUDY_TYPE_DESCR.STUDY_TYPE_ID(+)=STCD_STUDY_TYPE.ID AND STCD_STUDY_TYPE_DESCR.LANG_ID(+) = 1 )
                             AND ( STPR_STUDY.ID=STPR_STD_SPECIES.STD_ID(+) ) 
                             AND ( STPR_STD_SPECIES.SPECIES_ID=STCD_SPECIES.ID(+) ) 
                             AND ( STPR_STD_SPECIES.STRAIN_ID=STCD_STRAIN.ID(+) ) 
                             AND ( STCD_SPECIES.ID=STCD_SPECIES_DESCR.SPECIES_ID(+) AND                 STCD_SPECIES_DESCR.LANG_ID(+) = 1 )
                             AND ( STCD_TA.ID(+)=STPR_CMPND.TA_ID ) 
                             AND ( STCD_TA_DESCR.TA_ID(+)=STCD_TA.ID AND STCD_TA_DESCR.LANG_ID(+)=1 ) 
                             AND ( ILRS_DOSE.UAR=STPR_STD_ANML.UAR ) 
                             AND ( ILRS_DOSE.SESSION_ID=STRS_SESSION3.ID ) 
                             AND ( STPR_STUDY_DET.SUPPLIER_ID=STCD_RESRCE2.ID(+) ) 
                             AND ( STCD_UNIT_DESCR10.UNIT_ID(+)=STCD_UNIT10.ID AND STCD_UNIT_DESCR10.LANG_ID(+) = 1 )
                             AND ( STPR_STUDY_DET.DURATION_UNITS_ID=STCD_UNIT10.ID(+) ) 
                             AND ( STCD_STUDY_TYPE_DESCR.STUDY_TYPE_ID(+)=STCD_STUDY_TYPE.ID AND STCD_STUDY_TYPE_DESCR.LANG_ID(+) = 1 )
                             AND ( STCD_UNIT_DESCR10.UNIT_ID(+)=STCD_UNIT10.ID AND STCD_UNIT_DESCR10.LANG_ID(+) = 1 )
                             AND ( ILRS_DOSE.ACT_ID=STCD_ACT4.ID(+) ) 
                             AND ( STCD_ACT_DESCR4.ACT_ID(+)=STCD_ACT4.ID AND STCD_ACT_DESCR4.LANG_ID(+) = 1 )
                             AND ( STPR_STUDY_DET.STD_STATUS_ID=STCD_STUDY_STATUS.ID(+) ) 
                             AND ( STCD_STUDY_STATUS.ID=STCD_STUDY_STATUS_DESCR.STUDY_STATUS_ID(+) AND STCD_STUDY_STATUS_DESCR.LANG_ID(+) = 1 )
                             AND ( ( STPR_OPTIONS.OPT_ID = 1 ) ) 
                             AND ( STCD_VEH_SOLV.TYPE (+) = 0 ) 
                             AND ( ( STPR_OPTIONS.OPT_ID = 1 ) ) 
                             AND ( ( STPR_OPTIONS.OPT_ID = 1 ) ) 
                             AND ( STCD_RESRCE2.TYPE(+) = 3 ) 
                             AND ( STCD_RESRCE2.TYPE(+) = 5 ) 
                             AND 
                             STPR_STUDY.STD_REF IN(X,Y,Z)
```

Involving various tables and has many filters. In the Web API I created that has he direct DB access, I was giving the entire Query in a `var` and passed them in the `OracleCommand` and retrieved the result.
As the Query is complex I was not able to create the Entity Data Model. So what I am doing is creating the Model Class ad Database Context manually like

```
public class StdDataModel
{
    [Key]
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
    public int SESSION_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public DateTime SESSION_START_DATE { get; set; }
    public DateTime SESSION_START_TIME { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> SESSION_END_DATE { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> SESSION_END_TIME { get; set; }
    public string DOSE_ACTIVITY { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> SESSION_DURATION_MINUTES { get; set; }
    public int RESULT_WEEK { get; set; }
    public int RESULT_DAY { get; set; }
    public DateTime RESULT_DATE { get; set; }
    public DateTime RESULT_TIME { get; set; }
    public string ANIMAL_NAME { get; set; }
    public string GROUP_NAME { get; set; }
    public string SEX { get; set; }
    public string STUDY_NUMBER { get; set; }
    public string COMPOUND { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Decimal> TEST_MATERIAL_AMOUNT { get; set; }
    public string ROUTE_OF_ADMINISTRATION { get; set; }
    public string ADMINSTRATION_ROUTE_UNITS { get; set; }
    public string VECHICLE { get; set; }
    public string PRE_STUDY_DATA { get; set; }
}}
AND
public class StdDataContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<StdDataModel> details { get; set; }
}
}
```

Now in the Controller I am not able to understand how to pass the entire Query in the Entity Framework.Can we pass the entire query in to variable and pass them.Or do I need to convert them in to the LinQ statement.As most of the samples I googled are just using the LinQ I am kind of Stuck. Any help with this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Take a look at [SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.DbSet%601.SqlQuery);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) method.

Comment: And I'd suggest that you adopt the `join` syntax instead of `from x,y,z where...`

Comment: @GiladGreen I am not getting you. Can you please little more in detail.

Comment: Ya, read about joins in sql/linq

Comment: @GiladGreen So you are asking me to change with the Query right. I was thinking if you asking me to join the X,Y,Z that are passed and pass them as parameterized input

Comment: Ya I'm suggesting that in the future use a join syntax instead of a from syntax - will help you avoid bugs of forgetting one of the wheres

Comment: @GiladGreen this query is given by the client and we just using this query to reterive the data from clients DB. Is there any way to deal with this query as such in the entity framework.